# Product of ideals generated by linear forms that has zero dimension

Tags: commutative-algebra

Let $k$ be a field, $R=k[x_1,\dots,x_r]$ the polynomial ring in $r$ indeterminates and $I_1,I_2\dots,I_d$ homogeneous ideals of $R$ generated by linear forms. Define $J = I_1 I_2 \cdots I_d$ and suppose that $\dim R/J = 0$.

> Question: Is it true that $(R/J)_d = 0$? If yes, how can we see that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the $I_i$ are generated by homogeneous linear forms, they are prime ideals.   Since $J \subset I_i$, you have that
$$\mathrm{ht}~J \leq \mathrm{ht}~I_i$$
for all $i$.  Since you claim that $J$ has codimension $r$, it must be the case that each $I_i$ has height $r$, which in turn means it is equal to the homogenous maximal ideal $M =(x_1,\ldots,x_r)$.  Now the result follows since $(R/M^d)_d =0$.

Comment: Yes.  For quotients of polynomial rings, it is true that $ht I = dim R - dim(R/I)$.  To make the answer clearer, I'll update it.

Comment: My favorite first books are "Computational Algebraic Geometry by Hal Schenck" and "Ideals, Varieties and Algorithms" by Cox Little and O'Shea.